# How Does A Filter Work?

Tags: synthesizer, filter

I was reading secret synths, and understood how the phase shift between two identical signals can result in filtering. But the way it'd written makes it seem like the filters attentuating is different from phase shifting. Like, the filter does both phae shifting and attentuating. But can I ask why there is phase shifting?

Comment: See https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/28750/why-do-low-pass-and-high-pass-filters-generate-a-phase-shift You can get linear-phase EQs, but they have a side-effect of ringing instead. Frankly I don't even vaguely understand any of the math, but there's a tradeoff that can be implemented to make both side-effects minimal. https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/16448/non-linear-equalizer-vs-linear-equalizer